# CSS <ui:Checkbox> how to reduce vertical spacing in lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, css, tag

I have an iteration of checkboxes. There is almost 1 new line of space between these checkboxes. How do I reduce this with css. I tried

```
.THIS .myCheckbox{
  display: inline-block;
  padding-bottom: 0.1em;
  float: left;  
}
```

But this does not seem to reduce the space, below is my iteration

```
  <aura:iteration items="{!v.records}" var="item" indexVar="indx"> 
       <ui:inputCheckbox aura:id="checkbox" 
                          value="{!item.checkboxValue}" 
                          text="{!item.val}" 
                          name="{!indx}" 
                          label="{!item.val}" 
                          change="{!c.selected}"
                          class="myCheckbox"/>    
    </aura:iteration>
```

Comment: why are you adding &nbsp; in iteration ?

Comment: @ManjotSingh I had some text behind it, I removed it. But any suggestions to my question?

Comment: @Thomas You apparently didn't remove it from your source code; I just tried your code in my org, and it doesn't have the extra line of space.

Comment: after removing &nbsp; there is no space between checkboxes

Comment: Thx for pointing this out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `&nbsp;` is creating the extra line in your presentation; without it, you'll see that they are neatly stacked on top of each other.